# Problems with Jira gadget configuration screen

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I keep running in to strange issues when writing gadgets for Jira. I get problems like the options being clipped out of view, reconfiguration not working and most annoyingly: projectOrFilterPicker not working.

Most of the weird issues I run in to I can work around which is what I've done however I need to allow the user to use that quick search box for selecting a project or a filter. However, as soon as I include one of these dialog boxes the gadget just loads endlessly and if I resize the screen (one of the workarounds I use for other things) I get an error 500.

A weird thing is that it works locally on the Atlassian SDK test Jira (V 4.4) but not on my workplaces full test server (V 2.1.3).

This is some of the code I'm using and I can post more if necessary:

```
var projectPicker = AJS.gadget.fields.projectOrFilterPicker(gadget, "projectId", args.projectOptions);
```

args.projectOptions are defined here:

```
args: function()
{

    return [
        {
        key: "projectOptions",
        ajaxOptions:  "/rest/gadget/1.0/filtersAndProjects" 
    }
    ];
}()
```

Any insight/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code to the top of the gadget javascript:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://iedev255/s/531/4/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:autocomplete/jira.webresources:autocomplete.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://iedev255/s/531/4/4.1.2/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://iedev255/s/531/4/4.1.2/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common/global.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iedev255/s/531/4/2.1.3/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iedev255/s/531/4/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:jira-global/jira.webresources:jira-global.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iedev255/s/531/4/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:autocomplete/jira.webresources:autocomplete.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://iedev255/s/531/4/4.1.2/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common.js" ></script>
```

It solved a lot of my problems